# Searching for topic categories using mysqli

Tags: php, security, mysqli, sql-injection

Is this code safe from injection, xss and whole other attacks or no ?

The below code is for search box :

```
if(isset($_POST["query"]))
{
$output = '';
$string = $_POST['query'];
$search = htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$stmt = $con->prepare(" SELECT * FROM topics_categories WHERE cat_name LIKE 
? LIMIT 3");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$search);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$output .= '
<a href="topics.php?cat_id='.$row['cat_id'] .'">'.$row['cat_name'].'</a>';
}
echo $output;
}
```

Comment: I am guessing this code doesn't really work the way you expect it to.  Your `LIKE` clause is not really doing a `LIKE` search. And I have no idea as to why you would be using `htmlspecialchars()` the way you are.

Comment: it's work i just want to know it's safe or no , how should i using htmlspecialchars() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searches are customarily done using [HTTP GET requests rather than POST requests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/504947/1157100), since they do not modify information on the server.

---

You are not applying escaping correctly.

- Why are you performing HTML escaping here?

  > ```
  > $search = htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  > ```

  The data in the `cat_name` column should not be HTML-escaped, so it would be inappropriate to HTML-escape the search term.
- You are neglecting to perform HTML escaping on `$row['cat_name']`.  When you are embedding text in HTML, you need to escape it using `htmlspecialchars()`.  Otherwise, if the `cat_name` happens to contain a string that looks like an HTML tag, the page could break.

---

Furthermore, I wouldn't bother constructing `$output`.  It would be simpler to `echo` each line of output as it comes.  That gets rid of two lines of clutter: `$output = ''` and `echo $output`.  (There might be a slight difference in performance, but I wouldn't worry about it.)

Comment: The lines before the link are safe ? because i didn't escape url yet .
at the first i want to make sure the $_POST['query'] and sql query are safe then if they safe i want know how to make the url safe too

Comment: Strings that should be escaped need to be escaped for a reason.  Conversely, strings that don't need to be escaped should not be escaped. Don't randomly sprinkle escaping functions here and there "just in case" — you must understand _why_ you are applying the escape. In the case of your SQL query, `$stmt->bind_param(…)` will apply the SQL string escaping for you. Any escaping that you manually apply to `$string` will just corrupt the query string.